# python plot from groupby do not show the x-axis values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

[image]The following groupby function is used on my dataframe. The plot however does not print the x-axis values. What could be going wrong here?

```
df.groupby(['funding_round_type']).sum().transform(lambda x: x/np.sum(x)*100)
ax=df.groupby(['funding_round_type']).sum().transform(lambda x: x/np.sum(x)*100)
ax.plot()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because your x-axis is categorical instead of numeric (including datetime). Default of [pandas.Series.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html) uses `plot(kind='line')` whose x-axis needs to be numeric (including datetime) to show xticks properly. So if you want to use categorical x-axis, you need to change the argument of `kind` to `plot(kind='bar')` as an example. Therefore, below would work for your data:

```
ax.plot(kind='bar')
```

Hope this helps.